# $.GetJson data is empty

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm having a `MVC` project where I have a `Json` call to the controller. This call returns nothing, even thou it always should return either true or false.

My code looks like this

*Register.cshtml*

```
function registera() {
    var $email = $('#register-email'),
        $password = $('#register-password'),
        $repeatPassword = $('#register-repeatPassword'),
        $firstname = $('#register-firstname'),
        $lastname = $('#register-lastname'),
        $message = $('#message-register');

    if ($password.val() != $repeatPassword.val()) {
        $message.className = 'alert alert-danger';
        $message.html("Both passwords must be identical");
    } else {
        $message.className = 'alert';
        showLoadingText($message);

        register($email.val(), $password.val(), $firstname.val(), $lastname.val(), function (data) {
            if (data.IsValid()) {
                $message.html('');
                $message.className = '';
            } else {
                $message.className = 'alert alert-danger';
                $message.html(data.Message());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

*script.js*

```
function register(email, password, firstname, lastname) {
    $.get("/Account/GetJson_Register", { email: email, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname }, function (data) {
        return data;
    }, 'json');
};
```

*AccountController.cs*

```
public ActionResult GetJSON_Register(string email, string password, string firstname, string lastname)
{
    repository.Register(email, password, firstname, lastname);

    return Error.Instance.Message != ""
        ? Json(new { IsValid = false, Message = Error.Instance.Message })
        : Json(new { IsValid = true, Message = Error.Instance.Message });
}
```

Comment: `return` inside the callback isn't the same as return from function even if you could due to asynchronous nature of ajax. Your function returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes little sense to "return" from the asynchronous success-callback in this context. In this case looks like the register function is missing an additional parameter for it's own callback function - it isn't that the "data is empty" so much as the appropriate function is never invoked.

Compare with:

```
function register(email, password, firstname, lastname, callback) {
    $.get("/Account/GetJson_Register", { email: email, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname },
          function (data) {
            // Invoke the callback, supplying the relevant result
            callback(data);
          }, 'json');
};
```

Do note that the above code uses a wrapper in a silly fashion to show a point. Consider if it were written like the following, where the user-code provided callback is still invoked on-success. This works because neither the parameters nor the function context needed to be changed.

```
function register(email, password, firstname, lastname, callback) {
    $.get("/Account/GetJson_Register", { email: email, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname },
          callback, 'json');
};
```

Of course, the unified method is to [use Promises](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html) instead of manual callback wrapping. In this case, because [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) already returns a promise the code could be written like so:

```
function register(email, password, firstname, lastname) {
    // Return $.Promise returned from $.get as created by the wrapped $.ajax..
    return $.get("/Account/GetJson_Register",
                 { email: email, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname },
                 'json');
};

function showError (message) {
    $message.className = 'alert alert-danger';
    $message.html(message);
}

register($email.val(), $password.val(), $firstname.val(), $lastname.val())
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.IsValid) {
            $message.html('');
            $message.className = '';
        } else {
            // This should be .Message and not .Message(), etc.
            showError(data.Message);
        }
    })
    // It is also good to handle cases when a non-200 OK occurs
    .fail(function (xhr, message) {
        showError("Registration failed: " + message);
    });
```